# Online editor for mathematical expressions (web-app)

Tags: web-apps, math, editor

I recently used https://www.imatheq.com/corpsite/index.html.

It's pretty cool but seems that with the free version when you save the image it adds a weird background color to it.

The quality of the image is also not good.

Are there any other good freely available mathematical expressions writer web-apps?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be doing a fair bit of mathematical typesetting I would suggest learning how to use [MathJax](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/) either directly or via tools such as [Jupyter](https://jupyterbook.org/content/math.html).

Jupyter allows you to run a server where you can combine MarkDown, MathJax and code, *including executing the code and including the results.*

It is

- **Free**, *Gratis & Open Source*
- Cross Platform
- The user interface is via the browser
- Results can be saved to pdf and a number of other formats

Answer (score 0):

Some mathematicians use Overleaf as free equation editor online. Here is a link https://www.overleaf.com. It is Latex based, and very popular among math people